# Get current place type in Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm working with Google Places API.

I'm getting right the place in my log, but I just want the name of the type of place. Let's say this is my output

> Place 'Parque Las Tejas' has likelihood: 0.950000 Type: [69, 1013, 34]

So, at first I get the position where I am, the likelihood of where I am and then I just used:

```
List<Integer> types = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPlaceTypes();
```

thinking it would return like "park" or "square"  but instead of that I get those array of numbers `[69, 1013, 34]`.

According to what I [read here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=es-419), there is lots of types that defines a certain place.

What I want is to get that kind of types only, so if I'm at a restaurant I don't want the name of the restaurant but instead just the type, so `"Restaurant"` will be my output.

I need this because I want to give the user options depending on what type of place they are.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you tell me, `placeLikelihood` is an instance of the class `PlacePicker`? Could be useful if you can provide the code where you initialise and use the Place picker

Comment: I'm out of home but the example is from here https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List<Integer>` that you get is actually the id of type of places, according to the docs:

> The elements of this list are drawn from Place.TYPE_*

The list is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place). So basically your goal is to convert int code to a string using this list. You can find your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235406/7915814), basically you obtain all the fields from the `Place` class, find all the fields that start with "TYPE", get the int value and compare it to the value that you get from the `getPlaceTypes()`.

Answer (score 1):

even though this is an old post, it will help you if you an encountering this issue,
i was encountering this issue 
and here is my approach

```
 List<Place.Type> types = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getTypes();
```

to get all the type you can use a foreach loop

```
    for(Object type:types){
// get all individual type
}
```